# Adding table rows through For-Loop

Tags: c#, datagrid, for-loop, datatable

I am trying to write a program that requires me to add data to a datagrid. There's a pattern, but I can't seem to figure out how to decently get this data done through a For-Loop.

This is my code without using a For-Loop:

```
table.Rows.Add("0", "0", "0", "0", "0");
table.Rows.Add("0", "0", "0", "1", "0");
table.Rows.Add("0", "0", "1", "0", "0");
table.Rows.Add("0", "1", "0", "0", "0");

table.Rows.Add("1", "0", "0", "0", "0");
table.Rows.Add("1", "0", "0", "1", "0");
table.Rows.Add("1", "0", "1", "0", "0");

table.Rows.Add("1", "1", "0", "0", "0");
table.Rows.Add("1", "1", "0", "1", "0");

table.Rows.Add("1", "1", "1", "0", "0");
table.Rows.Add("1", "1", "1", "1", "0");
```

The last zero will be dynamically generated, no need to do anything with that.

Is this somehow possible to do through a For-Loop?

Comment: from where this data is coming? loop through the actual data source. you can simply bind the table with your data source , if any.

Comment: You already have readable and working code, why change it?

Comment: Calculations will be done on the numbers. For example, the first two numbers of the row are paired and have to be calculated with a specific - and dynamically set - operator. Same for the third and fourth number. Then, the outcome of those two pairs will be calculated again and filled in on the 5th entry of the row. Search for Truthtable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this loop, although it is not very readable. So if you can use your static code, use it.

```
bool allFieldsOne = false;
table.Rows.Add("0", "0", "0", "0", "0");
while (!allFieldsOne)
{
    DataRow lastRow = table.Rows[table.Rows.Count - 1];
    DataRow currentRow = table.Rows.Add();
    currentRow[4] = "0";
    for (int f = 3; f >= 0; f--)
    {
        if (lastRow.Field<string>(f) == "0")
        {
            currentRow[f] = "1";
            while (--f >= 0)
                currentRow[f] = "0";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            currentRow[f] = "1";
            allFieldsOne = f == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would that kind of for loop pattern be useful ? (it's the pattern used for truth table which is simply binary counting)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                   string.Format("{0:0000}",
                   Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToString(i, 2)))
                );
            }

/* 
OUTPUT
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
*/
```

Comment: The author's current code includes `30` in binary.  This would indicate the loop should count to `30` not `16`.

Comment: That would be 32 for a truth table and from the author itself : The last zero will be dynamically generated, no need to do anything with that.